# xslt transforming xml to text by skipping some elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform an XML file to text but I want also some elements not to be transformed.

e.g Input:

```
  <parent> Some parent text
     <child1>child text</child>
       more parent text
  </parent>
```

expected output:

```
  Some parent text <child1>child text</child> more parent text
```

my current XSLT:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

      <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template> 

      <xsl:template match="child1">
         <xsl:element name="child1">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But what what I get is:

```
Some parent text child text more parent text
```

is there anyway I can fix this to include some child elements?

Comment: If you want XML output then why are you using `method="text"`?

Comment: I can try that but as you can see the expected output xml elements are in the middle of texts.

Comment: I just tried xml too but not making any difference.

Comment: Is it the case that you don't want the `parent` element to appear in the output, but everything else stays the same?

Comment: not exactly other child elements will be transformed but yes only text part of parent node will be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to this XML input document:**

```
<parent> Some parent text
     <child1>child text</child1>
       more parent text
</parent>
```

**Will yield the requested (not well-formed XML) output document:**

```
 Some parent text
     <child1>child text</child1>
       more parent text
```

**Of course you can also match `child1` elements:**

```
  <xsl:template match="child1">
    <xsl:element name="child1_NEW">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

**And handle them differently:**

```
 Some parent text
     <child1_NEW>child text</child1_NEW>
       more parent text
```

Comment: it still ignore <child1> element but include its text.

Comment: I will take that back I was losing the elemets after transformation, thanks that helped me.